# Xamarin + Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I installed  Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015. Created New Project - Xamarin.Forms (Portable) and get error : A problem was encountered creating the sub project . This project required a Visual Studio update to load . Right-click on the project and chooes "Download Update" .

But there is not any "Download Update" . 
How I can solve this problem ?

Comment: Visual Studio update, not project update. Install [VS 2015 Update 2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx).

Comment: I installd the last version VS . My OS is Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

Open only the project that needs the update (not the solution) with VS. It should prompt you with what it needs and offer to install it.

Comment: Does not help for me. Keeps showing a message stating there is either a problem with my VS or my Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are working with the latest version of Xamarin, which now includes support for UWP apps. You can either [install the Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) or simply delete the UWP project in case you are not interested in deploying your app to a Windows 10 device.